# How to pass criteria to a SQL Server query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

Used by:

- EntityFramework - 6.2.0;
- MS Sql Server 2012;

In MS Access, I use the following query(`req_GroupsStud_CurGroup`):

```
SELECT req_GroupsStud_Stud.*, req_GroupsStud_Stud.id_group
FROM req_GroupsStud_Stud
WHERE (((req_GroupsStud_Stud.id_group)=[Forms]![frm_00_00_MainForm]![id_group_Frm]));
```

From the form, using the expression `[Forms]![Frm_00_00_MainForm]![Id_group_Frm]`, the parameter `[id_group_Frm]` is passed to the request.

**Questions.**
How in MS Sql Server to transfer in the query `req_GroupsStud_CurGroup` parameter 
`id_group_Frm "?
Or are there other tools in MS Sql Server and EntityFramework to get a similar data set?

**Update_1:**
Requirements for the request `req_GroupsStud_CurGroup`:
1. if changes are made to the record in the request, these changes should be displayed in the original source;

2. if the record is added to the request, then this record is displayed in the source;
3. the request is planned to be used in another request.

I managed to implement these requirements in MSAccess.

I do not understand how to do the same using `Entity-Framework` and `MS SQL Server`.

I tried the following methods:
**- method_1**

```
cntDB.req_GroupsStud_Stud.Load();
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter id_group_Param = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@id_group_frm", id_group);


                var sp_Get_Stud_var = cntDB.Database.SqlQuery<req_GroupsStud_Stud>("sp_Get_Stud @id_group_frm", id_group_Param).ToList();

                bs_Grid_2.DataSource = sp_Get_Stud_var;
                dataGridView2.DataSource = bs_Grid_2;
```

**- method_2**

```
cntDB.sp_Get_Stud(id_group);
```

Can not fully understand.
I think these methods will not meet the above requirements for the request.

Comment: Have you used LINQ before? Can you show us an existing EF query that you are using?

Comment: So you want to filter a table based on a particular value? A simple `Where(x => x.id_group == yourvalue)` is enough on Entity. You can also create an SP on SQL Server that filters by a parameter and use Entity to call the SP.

Comment: @mjwills Updated question

Comment: @EzLo Updated question